# Jade - id and variable in each...in function

Tags: pug

I want to use `each...in` function in Jade file

but while I use `#{...}`to set the variable, I can't set id in div.

Jade:

```
sidebars = ['home', 'club', 'bond']
each sidebar in sidebars
    div.side_bar_category#side_bar_#{sidebar} #{sidebar}
```

and it came out:

```
<div id="side_bar_" class="side_bar_category"></div><home> home</home>
<div id="side_bar_" class="side_bar_category"></div><club> club</club>
<div id="side_bar_" class="side_bar_category"></div><bond> bond</bond>
```

I want it become:

```
<div id="side_bar_home" class="side_bar_category">home</div>
<div id="side_bar_club" class="side_bar_category">club</div>
<div id="side_bar_bond" class="side_bar_category">bond</div>
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: `div.side_bar_category(id='side_bar_' + sidebar)= sidebar`

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to put your id attribute inside parenthesis so you can concat the attribute with your variable

```
  sidebars = ['home', 'club', 'bond']
  each sidebar in sidebars
    div.side_bar_category(id='side_bar_'+ sidebar) #{sidebar}
```